# How to show another domain for a reverse lookup

Tags: domain-name-system, reverse-dns, dns-zone

Today when someone do a reverse lookup for my website ip address, it gets my hosting server name (ie. server1.hosting.com). Instead, I want to show the hosted website domain (ie. mywebsite.com)

Can I set some kind of alias on the DNS zone to do that? How should it be?

Thank you

Comment: Too bad this is flagged as off topic as it is exactly what I need for my hosting.

Answer (score 2):

This usually needs to be done by the hosting provider, as they control the reverse zone with your IP address. Check their docs and/or ask their support to learn how to do this.

Regarding aliases: That is now how [reverse lookups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup) work.

If you have indeed control over the reverse zone for your IP address, the PTR record should look like this:

```
<ip>   PTR   www.example.com.
```

This would lead to a reverse lookup for your IP to result in `www.example.com`.

Comment: I have control over the DNS zone throught WHM

Comment: Do you have control for the forward zone (e.g. `example.com`) or the reverse zone? This is a major difference!

Comment: I want to put your answer as the right one, but aparently I can't because the topic is on hold and I don't know why. Could you review it? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a substantially large net block (range of continuous IP addresses), it’s most likely that your ISP/hosting provider retains control over the DNS zone for your IP address.  You would need to ask them to configure the PTR record corresponding to that IP address to `mywebsite.com`.

Comment: I have control over the DNS zone throught WHM

Comment: What I want to know is exactly how this  PTR record should be

Comment: You most likely only have control over the *forward* zone. A PTR record looks like `789.56.4.123.in-addr.arpa` but you should be able to just provide the relevant IP address to your ISP.